# How to change state inside 'new method' with Mobx

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I want to change state with a function that is at same store of state.
For example, I have some code like below.

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';

export default class AddressTime {
  @observable addressState = {
    departure: {
      road: '',
    }
  };

  departureAddress = () => {
      new window.daum.Postcode({
        oncomplete(data) {

        const roadAddr = data.roadAddress; 

        this.addressState.departure.road = roadAddr;
      })
}
```

I can make roadAddr by daum post api. and there is one more function in the method called oncomplete. 
So when I run 'departureAddress' function that says

> TypeError:this.addressState is undefined.

Maybe this error comes from the position error of this.addressState that is inside on function of one method.
Could you help me this problem?

PS) Must I use action or computed of mobx in this case to change state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about try this?

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';

export default class AddressTime {
    @observable 
    addressState = {
        departure: {
            road: '',
        }
    };

    @action
    departureAddress = () => {
        const _this = this
        new window.daum.Postcode({
            oncomplete(data) {

                const roadAddr = data.roadAddress; 

                _this.addressState.departure.road = roadAddr;
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works well. The problem was 'this' scope!

Comment: glad to help you!